# Which way is better to invite your facebook friends via an IOS/Android app?

Tags: mobile, android, ios, facebook

I am building a social community via an IOS and Android app, both apps are using "Post to friend wall" to invite friends to use with a direct link for the landing page of the app to download it.

However, as I've read recently from facebook, they will stop allowing applications to post on friends' walls; therefore, I wonder if there is a better experience to deliver invitations on facebook for users' friends.

Answer (score 4):

If you have to use Facebook for communication, I think the best way would be to use private messages, which has a supported API since last year (2012). For reference, look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9413419/286244) to the question [Send private messages to friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574431/send-private-messages-to-friends).

But using Facebook as invitation channel for other apps is maybe not the best approach, since there are a lot of [Facebook users who doesn't monitor there messages on a daily basis](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/janet-tavakoli/facebooks-fake-numbers-on_b_2276515.html). Since where on mobile devices, SMS would be the preferred way of communication. If cost is an issue - e-mail would be the choice.

Comment: On the Android platform, adding SMS support causes scary warnings during App install/download (because malicious applications can send text messages to pay services).  So, I recommend against adding SMS support to an application.  However, if your application already requires SMS support, SMS may be a good approach.